# Whats the meaning of the 1 Ket?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, eigenvalue, eigenvectors

I am talking this one:   $|1\rangle$. If I have 2 orthonormal states $|1\rangle$ and $|2\rangle$ in the 2D Hilbert space, does that imply the vector $\vec{\psi_n}=(1,2)$, if I would like to solve the equation for eigenvectors and eigenvalues?

The latter is given by: $\hat{A}$|$\psi_n$=$\lambda_n|$$\psi_n$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Depends (on the context maybe). Usually it is just a name and you could, for example, choose a basis in which
$$
|1\rangle = (1,0), \\
|2\rangle = (0,1).
$$